i want get appid in this function exports.usercustomclaim = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {});
I want get appid in this function
exports.usercustomclaim = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {});

I am using app in my project and I want to set up custom claim for that app. That's why I want to get appId, so I can set custom claim according to that.
// some other imports
const functions = require("firebase-functions/v1");
const functionsv2 = require("firebase-functions/v2");
// some other code 
exports.usercustomclaim = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  console.log(functionsv2.config().firebase.appId);
});

I am getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appId')


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
